# understandinf openshift source strategy

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd, minishift, redhat-containers

regarding to the BuildConfig YAML code bellow:

```
source:
 git:
  ref: TCPuniverse-patch-1
  uri: 'https://github.com/TCPuniverse/simple-webapp.git'
 type: Git
strategy:
 sourceStrategy:
  from:
    kind: ImageStreamTag
    name: 'python:3.6'
    namespace: openshift
output:
  to:
    kind: ImageStreamTag
    name: 'tpython-app-1:latest'
```

shouldn't we see "python:3.6" Image Stream Tag in Build > Images page?
And what does the "namespace: openshift" mean in strategy section?

Answer (score 1):

> And what does the "namespace: openshift" mean in strategy section?

It means, `https://github.com/TCPuniverse/simple-webapp.git` source will build using `python:3.6` imagestream tag in `openshift` project. And the built image would be pushed as `tpython-app-1:lates` imagestream in the project the buildconfig defined.

Comment: My project name in OKD is "my-project-1". I tried to change "namespace: openshift" to the "namespace: my-project-1" to match my own project name, but it complained about the image stream tag so I tried to create "python:3.6" image stream tab; I got another error pointing to the invalid characters in "python:3.6". if  "namespace: openshift" points to the project name, so why I got those errors? And why isn't "python:3.6" is not shown among the image stream tags?

Comment: Any help? I still stuck here. I changed sourceStrategy / from / namespace from "openshift" to my project name but it didn't work. Although it worked before this change, but why? what does "namespace: openshift" means if that isn't my project name?!

Comment: would you please help me on this?

Comment: AFAIK, okd provide python s2i image as ImageStream within `openshift` project. You can  check this using `oc get is python -n openshift`. Refer [here](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/using_images/s2i_images/python.html) for python s2i details. And check whether python ImageStreamTag 3.6 is existing or not using `oc describe is python -n openshift`. If it's not existing, you can try the build with existing other version.